# How to parse a CSV file

Tags: android, split, readline

I'm trying to read a file which consists of some lines and each line has 3 parts: id , name and surname. There is also an `EditText` where the user needs to enter his id and in case it matches with one of the ones read from the file it should show a dialog like this one: Are you "Name", "Username"?

I've tried doing the following thing but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
public String getDNI() {
    String[] parts = fichero.split("\\,");
    String DNI = parts[0];
    return DNI;
}

public String getNombre() {
    String[] parts = fichero.split("\\,");
    String Nombre = parts[1];
    return Nombre;
}

public String getEnunciado() {
    String[] parts = fichero.split("\\,");
    String Apellido = parts[2];
    return Apellido;
}



public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
   {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.identificacion);
      Button bSiguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_siguiente);
     dniText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dni_candidato);

     try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open(File);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            // Skips lines
            for (i = 0; i<= 100; i++) {
                reader.readLine();

            }
            fichero = reader.readLine();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



bSiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {



   try{
       longitud = dniText.getText().toString();
          user = Integer.parseInt(dniText.getText().toString());
          DNIWord(user);
          for (i = 0; i<= 100; i++) {
         if (longitud.equals(getDNI())){
             // (longitud.length()==8){
                     showDialog(DIALOG_CONFIRMAR_CANDIDATO);}

                else{
                 showDialog(DIALOG_ERROR_DNI);
                }

   }
   }
      catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {}
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where your `getDNI()`, `getNombre()`, or `getgetEnunciado()` functions are called. Is there more code we're missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach is to create a class to represent your user:

```
class User{
    public String nombre;
    public String enunciado;
    public String dni;

   public User(String nombre, String enunciado, String dni){
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.enunciado = enunciado;
      this.dni = dni;
   }

   public User(String csvLine){
       String[] values = csvLine.split(",");
       this(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
   }

}
```

I prefer the first constructor because it's easier to read.

Use like this:

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

...

     String s;
     while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         users.add(new User(s));
     }
```

or

```
 String s;
 String[] value;
 while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     values = s.split(",");
     users.add(new User(values[0], values[1], values[2])); <-- prefer this one
 }
```

To make it even better:

```
public static final int DNI = 0;
public static final int NOMBRE = 1;
public static final int ENUNCIADO = 2;

...

     String s;
     String[] value;
     while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         values = s.split(",");
         users.add(new User(values[DNI], values[NOMBRE], values[ENUNCIADO]));
     }
```

Now you can work with your users collection using `users.contains`, `users.getElementAt`, `Collections.sort`, `Collections.binarySearch` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another question helpful for parsing CVS in C++: [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c)

If you are open to other languages, like python, it might be much easier. For example, python has build-in csv tools:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html